# Show popup message before check for login

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, login, popup

I tried to show a `popup message` when customer tried to login. I add some code in `LoginPost.php` like in code below but it's not work.

**LoginPost.php :**

```
try {
      echo "  <script type='text/javascript'>
              alert('adadasd'); //This code i tried to popup a message
              </script>";

      $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($jsonObject[0]->EMAILOWNER, $jsonObject[0]->PASSWORDOWNER);
      $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
      $this->session->regenerateId();
      setcookie("Role", $jsonObject[0]->ROLE, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
      if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
         $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
         $metadata->setPath('/');
         $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
      }
```

How can i show a popup there? So the **login will not continue before the customer click the popup message**?

Comment: Customer tried to login means? do u want to show popup when customer enters login page?

Comment: No, when customer login from login page, there will be a popup on the login process, so after the popup clicked, the login process will continue.

Comment: u need pop up with yes or no button right?

Comment: Yes, can i add that popup on login process?

Comment: yes u can done this by javascript

Comment: Yes, so how could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this js code in your custom.js

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
    jQuery('.action.login.primary').on('click',function(){
         confirm('Do you want to continue the process?');
    });
});
```

Comment: so the js should added in custom js? can i add it to the LoginPost.php?